# OpenLayers data format

Tags: openlayers, data, format

I am just running an application using OpenLayers. All data is transfered from my database in GEOJSON format. My current task is to review the implementation of the data format. Important characteristics are:

1) Transfered data size - the smallest possible file
2) Speed of drawing on the map - how quickly received file is drawn on a map
3) Possibility to store circles - possibility to define circle feature

Points 1) and 2) are quite obvious. As I am transfering geometries and feature attributes as well, I can event imagine transfering these in separate files if it is beneficial form size and / or speed point of view.

Point 3) is related to GEOJSON limitations - there is no "circle" shape. At first I defined circles as points with radius. The issue is, that "big" circles don't fire click event on the whole area until I increase render buffer attribute. But it significantly decreases peformance. Now I define circles as polygons with many points. Unfortunately it impacts size of the files and the application performance as well in case more circles are on a map.

Please, could anybody advice, from practical experience, which file format(s) is(are) the best from the 3 points listed above?

Answer (score 1):

Practical experience notwithstanding, I do believe [FlatGeoBuf](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/flatgeobuf.html) via GDAL addresses your concerns for each point. [GitHub Page for FlatGeoBuf](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/flatgeobuf)

1) Very efficient binary encoding, which GeoJSON is certainly not
2) Provided buffers are trusted using GDAL, should be quite performant
3) OGC Simple Features are supported, which should include circles as Curves as of OGC SF 1.21 (2011).

FlatGeoBuf is a very nascent format which was only just recently added to GDAL, but it does seem quite promising, and the goals the project has in terms of being suitable for streaming and random access means it is designed very targeted towards usage similar to what you propose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GeoJSON is well supported by OpenLayers and is very efficient for parsing by JavaScript. The circle rendering problem can be solved by changing the geometry as features are loaded.

```
source.on('addfeature', function(event) {
  var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();
  var radius = event.feature.get('radius');
  if (geometry.getType() == 'Point' && radius) {
    event.feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Circle(geometry.getCoordinates(), radius));
  }
});
```